# Rails Routes - Nested single resource with :id, NOT :resource-name_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

In my routes I have a nested resource like so:

```
namespace :public, path: "/" do
constraints(Subdomain::Public) do
  namespace :v1 do
    post  "/webhooks/:id/test",  to: "webhooks#test" 
    resources :webhooks,       only: [ :index, :show, :create, :update, :destroy ]
```

The post webhook route becomes:

```
POST   /v1/webhooks/:id/test(.:format)
```

This is good. However I want to clean this up a bit like so:

```
namespace :public, path: "/" do
constraints(Subdomain::Public) do
  namespace :v1 do
    resources :webhooks, only: [ :index, :show, :create, :update, :destroy ] do
      post :test
    end
```

This results in a route like this:

```
POST   /v1/webhooks/:webhook_id/test(.:format)
```

Not good. I want a regular :id in the path.  What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  resources :webhooks, only: [ :index, :show, :create, :update, :destroy ] do
    member do
      post :test
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

That's just how the Rails router sets things up. If you don't like the way it's generated, you can always make a manual route with the parameter names you'd prefer, like you've done in your first example.

Generally I'd say it's best two embrace the convention here rather than buck it. This is just the name of a parameter, not something visible to the end-user. The more you break convention, the more non-standard your code will be and the harder it will be to maintain.